# C++ Multiple definition of main

Tags: c++

(Sorry for bad english)
Hi guys ! 
My program doens't want to running because an error, thank you kindly help me.

My source:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "function_h.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int reponse(0);
    ifstream myfile("dico.txt");

    cout << "1. Mode solo | 2. Mode multi" << endl;
    cout << "> ";
    cin >> reponse;
    if (reponse > 0 || reponse < 3)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        if (reponse == 1)
        {

        }
    } else { cout << "Une reponse valide." << endl; }

}
```

**function.cpp**

```
#include "main.cpp"
#include "function_h.h"
using namespace std;

string Melange(string mot)
{
    int position(0);
    string result;
    while (mot.size() != 0)
    {
        result += mot[position];
        mot.erase(position, 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**function_h.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTION_H_H_INCLUDED
using namespace std;
string Melange(string mot);

#endif
```

[Error](http://prntscr.com/38tjnu)

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
#include "main.cpp"
```

Usually you don't want (need) to include `.cpp` files (compilation units) anywhere (unless you want to include *externed template class definitions*)!

Comment: Re "Never, ever include .cpp files anywhere!", I would tend to degree. An implementation file designed to be included should IMHO be named e.g. ".hpp". Critical note for Visual Studio users: when deciding whether to compile the file or not, Visual Studio cares more about the original "kind" selected in the creation dialog, than about the filename extension.

Comment: Re the now updated "Never, ever include .cpp files (compilation units) anywhere (unless you want to include externed template class definitions)!", well that's bad advice. It's like an uncritical "never use exceptions", just because some novice got problems that way. Including ordinary implementation can be a good way to factor out compiler- and system- dependent code, since one can control the file selection via the compiler's include path. The preprocessor is just another tool here. Use the tool best suited to the purpose, no matter if it's unconventional.

Comment: Oh yes. For it's true, it's pretty *unusual*, as far as I know, to use the preprocessor for such purpose. But I tend to do it all the time, combined with symbolic directory links. It works nicely. :-)